# How to Connect the Web API(IIS Deployed) to MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm sorry to ask dumb question but how do I connect my web API to my LocalDB? When Debugging it in visual studio it connects to the database but it doesn't seems to work on my deployed instance. I read about application pool and tried changing it but the website just became inaccessible. The connection string was not wrong, Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `inaccessible` mean? If you do not have internet connection then any site becomes inaccessible! So I suggest you share some screenshot/error log that you see when you access the site. Otherwise no one will be able to provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: For more information about connect the Web API to LocalDB, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string